# Chamar outros dados de uma entidade

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Criei uma entidade de banco de dados e uma dropdownlist. Quando eu clico em um item da list, eu quero chamar os outros dados. Como faço ??

Segue codigo

```
    public ActionResult dbExample()
    {
        copaDBEntities entity = new copaDBEntities();
        var getCopaList = entity.copa.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getCopaList, "id", "ano");
        ViewBag.copalistano = list;

        return View();
    }
}
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#CopaList").change(function () {
    $("#msg").text("A copa de " + $("#CopaList option:selected").text() + " teve como país(es) sede(s) : " + 

        + "O Campeão foi " +  + "O Vice Campeão foi " + 
       )
})
```

imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como assim *"chamar os outros dados"*, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: no código c# só mostra o ano. Eu quero que mostra a sede, o campeão e o vice desse ano.

Comment: Você terá de fazer uma requisição para o c# para pegar o resto dos dados.

Answer (score 0):

Você ter este exemplo como base:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> SelecionarPorProjeto(int id)
    {

        copaDBEntities entity = new copaDBEntities();
        var getCopaList = entity.copa.ToList();

        //Retorna o valor em JSON
         return Json(getCopaList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Na View

```
 <script>
        $("#CopaList").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Subprojetos/SelecionarPorProjeto/" + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#SubprojetoId").empty();
                    $("#SubprojetoId").append('<option value>Selecione...</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                        $("#SubprojetoId").append('<option value="' + element.ProjetoId + '">' + element.Text + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```